/usr/bin/node can't run due to an Exec format error
On Ubuntu 22.04 over windows (WSL) when I try to run node I get the error:

-bash: /usr/bin/node: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

I tried to reinstall it with
 sudo apt install --reinstall nodejs

And when it didn't help to completely uninstall it and npm and install them fresh.
running file on the file gives the same result as running it on ls which works.
$ file /usr/bin/node
/usr/bin/node: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=d7abab52c01bf27bc053d24b0fad7f95c9e50d2f, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
$ file /usr/bin/ls
/usr/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=897f49cafa98c11d63e619e7e40352f855249c13, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped

How can I fix my node?
MY WSL and Windows versions:
WSL version: 2.2.4.0
Kernel version: 5.15.153.1-2
WSLg version: 1.0.61
MSRDC version: 1.2.5326
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore version: 10.0.26091.1-240325-1447.ge-release
Windows version: 10.0.22621.3880

Ubuntu distribution:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy


I spun up an Ubuntu 22.04 WSL with the same node BuildID and can't reproduce this issue. It sounds similar to an ELF alignment bug that used to affect gzip on WSL - please [edit] your question to include your WSL and Windows build versions (e.g. the output of wsl.exe --version in the Windows cmd or powershell)

@steeldriver, see edit.

Thanks - so the only thing I can see is that you're at 22.04.3 whereas I'm fully upgraded to 22.04.4 with libc6 version 2.35-0ubuntu3.8 - it may be worth updating + upgrading to see if anything changes.

@steeldriver, I upgraded, then uninstalled and installed and still have the same problem.

Sorry in that case I'm out of ideas - there have certainly been on-again-off-again issues with Windows/WSL and ELF binaries, so maybe this is another case - see for example gzip from Ubuntu Jammy doesn't execute (which I already mentioned) and Issue running x64 ELF since 1803 Build Windows [Version 10.0.17134.1]

@steeldriver You were on the right track - Just wrong WSL version. Oddly, the wsl --version command only tells you which version of WSL2 you are running, but it doesn't tell you if your default WSL version is WSL1.  That's done with wsl --status (and wsl -l -v).

@NotTheDr01ds ah thanks - I thought it had to be too similar to be unrelated

I uninstalled the apt version and downloaded the prebuilt binaries from the nodejs site and now it works.
Specifically the version for linux x64.

This is a known issue on WSL1, and I just reproduced it on my system to confirm that it is what you are seeing.  See this GitHub issue and this Stack Overflow question.  It's the same root problem as this AU question with gzip.  In the gzip case, the maintainers chose to patch the binary to work around the issue, but since the problem can surface on other binaries as well, such as the apt version of Node.js, as you've discovered.
From your comment:

I upgraded, then uninstalled and installed and still have the same problem

I'm guessing that your WSL default version is set to 1.  You can check this with:
wsl.exe --status

And confirm that Ubuntu is running as WSL1 with:
wsl.exe -l -v

Assuming your system supports WSL2, you should likely:
wsl --set-default-version 2
wsl --set-version <Ubuntu_distro_name> 2

You may want to backup any critical files on the slim chance that something goes wrong with the upgrade.
Side-note:  Not really a gripe, but I consider WSL1 to be deprecated even though the Microsoft team hasn't made that announcement.  To my knowledge, no bug has been fixed in WSL1 in over two years now, including this pretty critical issue.
My only "gripe" would be that I wish Microsoft would just make the deprecation official if that's the case.  It might be that they are waiting until they get the WSL2 9P filesystem performance issues fixed, but I just don't know.

Yes, I'm using WSL 1, but can't upgrade to WSL 2. This is a work computer and IT blocks WSL 2 for communication. As I note in my answer below, downloading the precompiled binaries from the nodejs site works.

@SIMEL Right - Often there are alternative binaries that won't have the issue, so I'm glad you found that solution as well.  As for WSL2 and network communication, you might want to try again with the latest version - You can now turn on "mirror mode" which will make the WSL map the Windows network interfaces into Ubuntu. This should have the effect of allowing Ubuntu to access anything network-wise that the Windows host can. While it's an unrelated question, see my answer here for how to turn it on.
